# Who is this Nemisis monster?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

While playing Diablo 3 today, I encountered an Elite monster named Nemisis several times. He popped up very randomly. I noticed he had a rune-like symbol under his name as well.He popped up twice in Act 1(I don't exactly remember what I was doing those times) and once in Act 2 (right before I went into the Witch's Den to fight her). He showed up probably a few hours in between his spawns. After being pulverized by him the first two times, the next time he showed up I was able to kill him. But an even stranger thing happened when I was about to kill him, as he had several shadows of myself attacking as well. He ended dropping a good bit of loot including a legendary item. What I want to know is his characteristics, like those rune-like symbols were, what triggers him to pop up, and anything else that would be helpful to know.

Comment: Can you add some more information? Where were you/what quests you were doing/how long was it between appearances? Also is it possible to get a screen shot of the runes?

Comment: I'm unable to get a screenshot right now, as I haven't found him again yet. And I'm afraid I don't remember too clearly where I was and what I was doing before the third time he appeared, which was when I killed him. I edited it to the best of my ability to give more info though. I apologize for the roughness of this question

Comment: afaik the nemesis is console only, please retag if i'm wrong

Comment: This was on a PS4 console

Comment: Worded differently, but the question is still asking about the nemesis boss. The answer is a lot better then any I could provide right now, as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nemesis can appear randomly, preceded by drum beats and a horn. Usually, they will be labeled "Killer of [someone on your friends list]", meaning they popped up in your friends game and killed them. If that nemesis is killed in your game, it will almost always drop a legendary or legendaries, and a gift for the friend that it had previously killed (even if they werent playing with you when you, or someone else in your party, killed the nemesis).

[Diablo wikia article for Nemesis](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nemesis_Kills)

Answer (score 1):

Nemesis bosses are enemies that have come into your game from another players game. I am pretty sure they have to defeat the player in their world to have a chance of coming through into another player's game. They are tougher, but have greater rewards for defeating them.

Comment: I had one show up while me and my mate were playing online Co-op. Beat us a few times and we ended up loosing it. But I also believe strange music starts playing when you are near one, as that is how we kept tracking it down.